# Why can't 'grub-mkconfig_lib` be opened, preventing a kernel upgrade?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I try to update my Ubuntu 12.04 and I have this error, then it update kernel. Any clue what I can do to fix this?

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic (3.2.0-25.40) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-25-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 24: .: Can't open /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.25.27); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo (1:12.04ubuntu4) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                               update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Generating grub.cfg ...
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 24: .: Can't open /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-25-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does the file `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` exist? Is it readable?

Comment: No, file didn't exists

Comment: So that's the problem, if you believe that you've not accidentally delete that file then please [make a bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Is there any way to fix this error? I can't make a bug report, because I have no idea when this error started, bug report will be very misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pasted the content of `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` underneath (pastebin was deleted as apparent from comment below). You can download it and place it in appropriate place, then retry.

Also, look for the file `/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib`. Generally, it's a symbolic link to `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib`. But do check if the original file is there. If in your case `/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` is the original file then open the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` and change its 21st line from `datarootdir="${prefix}/share"` to `datarootdir="${prefix}/lib"` then complete the upgrade.

```
# Helper library for grub-mkconfig
# Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

transform="s,x,x,"

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="${prefix}"
datarootdir="${prefix}/share"
datadir="${datarootdir}"
bindir="${exec_prefix}/bin"
sbindir="${exec_prefix}/sbin"
pkgdatadir="${datadir}/grub"

if test "x$grub_probe" = x; then
  grub_probe="${sbindir}/`echo grub-probe | sed "${transform}"`"
fi
if test "x$grub_mkrelpath" = x; then
  grub_mkrelpath="${bindir}/`echo grub-mkrelpath | sed "${transform}"`"
fi

if which gettext >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  :
else
  gettext () {
     printf "%s" "$@"
  }
fi

grub_warn ()
{
  echo "$(gettext "Warning:")" "$@" >&2
}

make_system_path_relative_to_its_root ()
{
  "${grub_mkrelpath}" "$1"
}

is_path_readable_by_grub ()
{
  path="$1"

  # abort if path doesn't exist
  if test -e "$path" ; then : ;else
    return 1
  fi

  # abort if file is in a filesystem we can't read
  if "${grub_probe}" -t fs "$path" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then : ; else
    return 1
  fi

  # ... or if we can't figure out the abstraction module, for example if
  # memberlist fails on an LVM volume group.
  if abstractions="`"${grub_probe}" -t abstraction "$path"`" 2> /dev/null ; then 
      :
  else
    return 1
  fi

  if [ x$GRUB_CRYPTODISK_ENABLE = xy ]; then
      return 0
  fi

  for abstraction in $abstractions; do
      if [ "x$abstraction" = xcryptodisk ]; then
      return 1
      fi
  done

  return 0
}

convert_system_path_to_grub_path ()
{
  path="$1"

  grub_warn "convert_system_path_to_grub_path() is deprecated.  Use prepare_grub_to_access_device() instead."

  # abort if GRUB can't access the path
  if is_path_readable_by_grub "${path}" ; then : ; else
    return 1
  fi

  if drive="`"${grub_probe}" -t drive "$path"`" ; then : ; else
    return 1
  fi

  if relative_path="`make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "$path"`" ; then : ; else
    return 1
  fi

  echo "${drive}${relative_path}"
}

save_default_entry ()
{
  if [ "x${GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT}" = "xtrue" ] ; then
    cat << EOF
savedefault
EOF
  fi
}

prepare_grub_to_access_device ()
{
  device="$1"

  partmap="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=partmap`"
  for module in ${partmap} ; do
    case "${module}" in
      netbsd | openbsd)
        echo "insmod part_bsd";;
      *)
        echo "insmod part_${module}";;
    esac
  done

  loop_file=
  case ${device} in
    /dev/loop/*|/dev/loop[0-9])
      grub_loop_device="${device#/dev/}"
      loop_file=`losetup "${device}" | sed -e "s/^[^(]*(\([^)]\+\)).*/\1/"`
      case $loop_file in
        /dev/*) ;;
        *)
          loop_device="${device}"
          device=`"${grub_probe}" --target=device "${loop_file}"` || return 0
        ;;
      esac
    ;;
  esac

  if dmsetup status $device 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'crypt[[:space:]]$'; then
    grub_warn \
      "$device is a crypto device, which GRUB cannot read directly.  Some" \
      "necessary modules may be missing from /boot/grub/grub.cfg.  You may" \
      "need to list them in GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES in /etc/default/grub.  See" \
      "http://bugs.debian.org/542165 for details."
    return 0
  fi

  # Abstraction modules aren't auto-loaded.
  abstraction="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=abstraction`"
  for module in ${abstraction} ; do
    echo "insmod ${module}"
  done

  fs="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=fs`"
  for module in ${fs} ; do
    echo "insmod ${module}"
  done

  if [ x$GRUB_CRYPTODISK_ENABLE = xy ]; then
      for uuid in "`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=cryptodisk_uuid`"; do
      echo "cryptomount -u $uuid"
      done
  fi

  # If there's a filesystem UUID that GRUB is capable of identifying, use it;
  # otherwise set root as per value in device.map.
  fs_hint="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=compatibility_hint`"
  if [ "x$fs_hint" != x ]; then
    echo "set root='$fs_hint'"
  fi
  if fs_uuid="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=fs_uuid 2> /dev/null`" ; then
    hints="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=hints_string 2> /dev/null`" || hints=
    echo "if [ x\$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then"
    echo "  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ${hints} ${fs_uuid}"
    echo "else"
    echo "  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ${fs_uuid}"
    echo "fi"
  fi

  if [ "x${loop_file}" != x ]; then
    loop_mountpoint="$(awk '"'${loop_file}'" ~ "^"$2 && $2 != "/" { print $2 }' /proc/mounts | tail -n1)"
    if [ "x${loop_mountpoint}" != x ]; then
      echo "loopback ${grub_loop_device} ${loop_file#$loop_mountpoint}"
      echo "set root=(${grub_loop_device})"
    fi
  fi
}

grub_get_device_id ()
{
  device="$1"
  if fs_uuid="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=fs_uuid 2> /dev/null`" ; then
    echo "$fs_uuid";
  else
    echo "$device"
  fi
}

grub_file_is_not_garbage ()
{
  if test -f "$1" ; then
    case "$1" in
      *.dpkg-*) return 1 ;; # debian dpkg
      *.rpmsave|*.rpmnew) return 1 ;;
      README*|*/README*)  return 1 ;; # documentation
    esac
  else
    return 1
  fi
  return 0
}

version_sort ()
{
  case $version_sort_sort_has_v in
    yes)
      LC_ALL=C sort -V;;
    no)
      LC_ALL=C sort -n;;
    *)
      if sort -V </dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        version_sort_sort_has_v=yes
    LC_ALL=C sort -V
      else
        version_sort_sort_has_v=no
        LC_ALL=C sort -n
      fi;;
   esac
}

version_test_numeric ()
{
  version_test_numeric_a="$1"
  version_test_numeric_cmp="$2"
  version_test_numeric_b="$3"
  if [ "$version_test_numeric_a" = "$version_test_numeric_b" ] ; then
    case "$version_test_numeric_cmp" in
      ge|eq|le) return 0 ;;
      gt|lt) return 1 ;;
    esac
  fi
  if [ "$version_test_numeric_cmp" = "lt" ] ; then
    version_test_numeric_c="$version_test_numeric_a"
    version_test_numeric_a="$version_test_numeric_b"
    version_test_numeric_b="$version_test_numeric_c"
  fi
  if (echo "$version_test_numeric_a" ; echo "$version_test_numeric_b") | version_sort | head -n 1 | grep -qx "$version_test_numeric_b" ; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

version_test_gt ()
{
  version_test_gt_sedexp="s/[^-]*-//;s/[._-]\(pre\|rc\|test\|git\|old\|trunk\)/~\1/g"
  version_test_gt_a="`echo "$1" | sed -e "$version_test_gt_sedexp"`"
  version_test_gt_b="`echo "$2" | sed -e "$version_test_gt_sedexp"`"
  version_test_gt_cmp=gt
  if [ "x$version_test_gt_b" = "x" ] ; then
    return 0
  fi
  case "$version_test_gt_a:$version_test_gt_b" in
    *.old:*.old) ;;
    *.old:*) version_test_gt_a="`echo -n "$version_test_gt_a" | sed -e 's/\.old$//'`" ; version_test_gt_cmp=gt ;;
    *:*.old) version_test_gt_b="`echo -n "$version_test_gt_b" | sed -e 's/\.old$//'`" ; version_test_gt_cmp=ge ;;
  esac
  dpkg --compare-versions "$version_test_gt_a" "$version_test_gt_cmp" "$version_test_gt_b"
  return "$?"
}

version_find_latest ()
{
  version_find_latest_a=""
  for i in "$@" ; do
    if version_test_gt "$i" "$version_find_latest_a" ; then
      version_find_latest_a="$i"
    fi
  done
  echo "$version_find_latest_a"
}

# One layer of quotation is eaten by "" and the second by
# sed; so this turns ' into \'.  Note that you must use the output of
# this function in a printf format string.

grub_quote () {
  sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"
}

gettext_quoted () {
  gettext "$@" | grub_quote
}

# Run the first argument through gettext, and then pass that and all
# remaining arguments to printf.  This is a useful abbreviation and tends to
# be easier to type.
gettext_printf () {
  gettext_printf_format="$1"
  shift
  printf "$(gettext "$gettext_printf_format")" "$@"
}

uses_abstraction () {
  device="$1"

  abstraction="`"${grub_probe}" --device "${device}" --target=abstraction`"
  for module in ${abstraction}; do
    if test "x${module}" = "x$2"; then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  return 1
}

print_option_help () {
  if test x$print_option_help_wc = x; then
      if wc -L  </dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      print_option_help_wc=-L
      elif wc -m  </dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      print_option_help_wc=-m
      else
      print_option_help_wc=-b
      fi
  fi
  if test x$grub_have_fmt = x; then
      if fmt -w 40  </dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      grub_have_fmt=y;
      else
      grub_have_fmt=n;
      fi
  fi
  print_option_help_lead="  $1"
  print_option_help_lspace="$(echo "$print_option_help_lead" | wc $print_option_help_wc)"
  print_option_help_fill="$((26 - print_option_help_lspace))"
  printf "%s" "$print_option_help_lead"
  if test $print_option_help_fill -le 0; then
      print_option_help_nl=y
      echo
  else
      print_option_help_i=0;
      while test $print_option_help_i -lt $print_option_help_fill; do
      printf " "
      print_option_help_i=$((print_option_help_i+1))
      done
      print_option_help_nl=n
  fi
  if test x$grub_have_fmt = xy; then
      print_option_help_split="$(echo "$2" | fmt -w 50)"
  else
      print_option_help_split="$2"
  fi
  if test x$print_option_help_nl = xy; then
      echo "$print_option_help_split" | awk \
      '{ print "                          " $0; }'
  else
      echo "$print_option_help_split" | awk 'BEGIN   { n = 0 }
  { if (n == 1) print "                          " $0; else print $0; n = 1 ; }'
  fi
}

grub_fmt () {
  if test x$grub_have_fmt = x; then
      if fmt -w 40 < /dev/null > /dev/null; then
      grub_have_fmt=y;
      else
      grub_have_fmt=n;
      fi
  fi

  if test x$grub_have_fmt = xy; then
      fmt
  else
      cat
  fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. And I found already existed bug on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1006772

Comment: The pastebin provided in this answer no longer exists.  Therefore, this answer is currently incomplete.

Comment: @ThomasW. pasted the content here now.